# I'm unable to interpret this error in stata

Tags: stata

After I open a dataset in stata, this code runs automatically in the backend.

```
use "C:\Users\vxk152430\Desktop\Stata_vxk152430\HW2\capm4.dta", clear
```

But then when I try to describe it by typing:

```
DES capm4
```

I get the following error.

```
variable capm4 not found
r(111);
```

please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`des` (and not DES, Stata is case-sensitive) needs an optional list of variable names, which can be omitted if you want to describe *all* of the variables. Since the name of the dataset is not one of your variables, Stata complains.

Here's a reproducible example demonstrating the issue:

```
sysuse auto, clear
des price
des
des auto
```

You can diagnose what went wrong by clicking on the numeric error code, which will give you more info about the short error message that Stata printed. You can also learn about this or any command by looking at the helpfile like this:

```
help des
```

Comment: Thank u very much Dimitriy :) got it.

Comment: @Vish Please select this as the answer if this helped by using the checkmark on the left

Comment: Thank you @Dimitriy. Apologies for the delay but I have accepted it as the answer.